# Google Places rejection iOS

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I am in the middle of developing an iOS app where there is a request to Google places and the results are displayed. Here is the code for fetching the information:

```
func fetchPlaceDetails(placeId: String) {
    let apiKey = "My Google API KEY"
    let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(placeId)&key=\(apiKey)"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        self.errorMessage = "Invalid URL"
        return
    }
}
```

I have set `placeid` somewhere else.

The error I get back from Google is this:

> "error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address [IP address], with empty referer"
> "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"

On the console side I get a (4xx) error.

Things I have tried:

1. Making a new API key
2. Hardcoding the placeID and the API key into the request
3. Using the same API key to display a map in the same app (this worked for the map but not for the places request)
4. Restricting the API to just the PlacesAPI
5. Unrestricting the key at all
6. I have Google Places enabled in the API Key
7. I am using package dependencies (8.3.0)

Right now I have the rawJSON data being displayed on the screen. The error above is what is returned. I would like the rawJSON from the request to be displayed.

Comment: Have you created an [api key restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys) for your api key that limits its use to your iOS app?  If so you cannot use that api key with a GET request.  You can only use that api key with the Google maps client for iOS. It's a bad idea to embed an unrestricted key in an app and it's also not great to include the apikey in a query string. If the key leaks you can end up with a big bill.

Comment: A better approach is to have a cloud function or similar that has access to the api key. Your iOS app then uses this server function to make the maps api request on its behalf. The server function can also make use of caching to reduce your maps api spend n

Comment: Yes, I have created an API key restriction for IOS use. This is good information to know. Your idea about the cloud function is a good idea and I'll get right on that.